# Styling form in Yii2 (ActiveField / ActiveForm)

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm really struggling getting my layout into Yii2. To be as close as possible to the state-of-the-art, I read about styling the `ActiveField` and `ActiveForm`, which kinda works, but not to 100%. Maybe you see whats wrong.

**Let me start of with my HTML, which I want to have:**

```
// normal state without any validations
<p>
    <label for="signup_name">Name, Surname:<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="signup_name" id="signup_name" value="" />
</p>

// input field after validation fails (ajax + reload)
<p>
    <label for="signup_email">E-mail:<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input class="error-input" type="text" name="signup_email" id="signup_email" value="" />
    <span class="error-msg">E-mail must be filled !</span>
</p>
```

**This is the current state, in which the layout is in:**

```
<p>
    <label class="control-label" for="signupform-username">Username</label>
    <input id="signupform-username" class="form-control" type="text" name="SignupForm[username]">
    <span class="error-msg">Username may not be empty</span>
</p>
```

**This is my PHP / Yii2-part**

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'form-signup',
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => "<p>{label}{input}{error}</p>",
        'errorOptions' => [
            'tag' => 'span',
            'class' => 'error-msg',
        ],
    ],
]);

echo $form->field($model, 'username', [
    'inputTemplate' => '{input}',
])->textInput(['autofocus' => false])
?>
```

**The Problems:**

- The `<span class="error-msg">` is always rendered, even though there is no error yet. To clarify: The span has no content and is rendered like this:
  `<span class="error-msg"></span>` (I want it to be there if there IS actually an error, not as a placeholder before
- I can't figure out on how to apply an error-class to the input, which works for the `ajax`-validation, as well as the not JS-way.

Any help is appreciated,
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add class for each field if you want

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control'])->label('Your Label',['class'=>'label-class']) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable ajax validation of input field.

```
 echo $form->field($model, 'username', ['enableAjaxValidation' => false]);
```

or

```
 echo $form->field($model, 'username', ['enableClientValidation' => false]);
```